# Why does this threaded method take 900 milliseconds to complete?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, optimization

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    StartToFillTree();
}

private void StartToFillTree( )
{
    try
    {
        tvFolders.Nodes.Clear();
        tvFolders.Nodes.Add( new TreeNode("Loading", -1, -1) );

        Thread explorerThread = new Thread( new ThreadStart( FillTreeInAnotherThread ) );
        explorerThread.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        //Do the catch
    }
}

private void FillTreeInAnotherThread()
{
    try
    {
        CreateTree(this.tvFolders);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        //Do the catch
    }
}


public void ClearTreeview( TreeView tv ) 
{
    tv.Nodes.Clear();
}

public void AddNodeToTreeview( TreeView tv, TreeNode node ) 
{
    tv.Nodes.Add( node );
}

public void CreateTree(TreeView treeView)
{
    try
    {
        TreeNode hoofdNode = new TreeNode( "NodeNam", 0, 0);
        AddDrivesToHoofdNode(hoofdNode); //This method takes 1 ms

        //This part takes 905 milliseconds if I can believe my profiler !!?? -----
        if( treeView.InvokeRequired )
        {
            treeView.Invoke( new ClearTreeviewDelegate( this.ClearTreeview ), new object[] { treeView } );
            treeView.Invoke( new AddNodeToTreeviewDelegate( this.AddNodeToTreeview ), new object[] { treeView, hoofdNode } );
        }
        else
        {
            treeView.Nodes.Clear();
            treeView.Nodes.Add(hoofdNode);
        }
        //End of 900ms part ?? -----


        AddFavorieteFolders(treeView);//This method takes 1 ms

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Do some catching
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have empty catch blocks? This is bad practice. Better not catch an exception than silently swallow it.

Comment: I'm catching the errors, but just removed the code for easy reading purposes here :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, why are you using threads for something that easy? Looks a bit over-designed. But you are maybe not showing us everything?

Also wrap the TreeView modifications with:

```
treeView.BeginUpdate();
// modify the tree here.
treeView.EndUpdate();
```

To get better performance.

Comment: You're right ... I was starting another thread to add 1 node to a treeview .. :-) a bit overkill :-) (it had grown over the years) ... It now takes 1 ms to complete. Thanks.

Comment: np. happens the best of us ;)

Answer (score 8):

You can't update UI components outside the UI thread.  All those Invoke calls are marshalling the updates back to the UI thread, effectively serialising your app again.

A typical approach to large trees is only loading child nodes when the parent is expanded rather than trying to fill the whole tree at the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

InvokeRequired takes some time to do its work. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx). Especially 
"If the control's handle does not yet exist, InvokeRequired **searches up the control's parent chain until it finds a control or form that does have a window handle.** If no appropriate handle can be found, the InvokeRequired method returns false."
So it takes some time

Answer (score 2):

Are you calling `BeginUpdate` on your `TreeView` control before clearing and adding new nodes, and then calling `EndUpdate` when you're done adding nodes?  If you don't make these calls, your `TreeView` will attempt to repaint itself after each added node - missing this can make code that is otherwise fine run extremely slowly, especially when adding a large number of nodes.

Comment: Forgot this too. Thanks for the tip.